# Merging and appending a list of ffdf dataframes

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

I would like to read a vector of CSV files names as `ffdf` data frames and combine them into one big `ffdf` data frame. I have found solutions using other `r` packages; however, my issue is my data (combined) can reach 40GB which definitely needs to be stored on disk, as `ff` package does, and not in the RAM. There are awesome [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23555961/13818750) here using RAM storage, as far as I know.

```
library(ffbase)
library(ff)

# Create list of csv files
csv_files <- list.files(path = input_path,
                        pattern="*.csv",
                        full.names = T)

# my approach so far
# this use fread, and it appears to be consuming RAM 

# Read the files in, assuming comma separator
csv_files_df <- lapply(csv_files, function(x) {
y<-unlist(str_split(x, "[.]"))[1]
    assign(y,
   as.ffdf(fread(x,stringsAsFactors = T)))})

# Combine them
combined_df <- do.call("ffdfappend", lapply(csv_files_df, as.ffdf))
```

When I try to combine them, it fires this error.

```
> combined_df <- do.call("ffdfappend", lapply(csv_files_df, as.ffdf))
Error in ffdfappend(list(virtual = list(VirtualVmode = c("double", "integer",  : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

Summary: I would like to read and merge the CSV files using only `ff` package without the need for another package to avoid OOM (Out Of Memory) status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ffdfappend()` function only takes two data arguments - `x` and `y`.  When you provide a list, it is assuming some of the data frames are the other arguments to `ffdfappend()`.  To use this function in the way you intend, you probably need to write it in a loop, something like this:

```r
csv_files <- list.files(path = input_path,
                        pattern="*.csv",
                        full.names = T)

# my approach so far
# this use fread, and it appears to be consuming RAM 

read <- function(x) {
  y<-unlist(str_split(x, "[.]"))[1]
  assign(y,
         as.ffdf(fread(x,stringsAsFactors = T)))}

# Read the files in, assuming comma separator
out <- read(csv_files[1])

for(i in 2:length(csv_files)){
  out <- ffdfappend(out, read(csv_files(i)))
}
```